# Connection to SharePoint through python issue ( atleast one time have to login to SharePoint website manually)

Tags: python, windows, sharepoint

I have a python code to establish SharePoint connection.

Issue is that every day once, twice or more I have to login to SharePoint website in browser manually then only my script is able to establish connection. Otherwise it keeps on trying to connect in loop. Sometimes it connects without even me logging into the website but most of the times it don't.

I am running the code in windows root account but the SharePoint username which I am using to connect to SharePoint thru code is different
[screenshot of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPDyR.jpg)

Please help how to solve this issue. I don't want to login to my website daily morning so that my script can connect to SharePoint as I will schedule the script through task scheduler and don't want any manual intervention.

I am not able to figure out what to try.

Earlier my script was not running at all then once I manually logged in to website then it script was to establish connection successfully.

```
import time
username = "user@company.com"
password = "Password$123"
site_url = "https://companygroup.sharepoint.com/sites/123456"
ctx = ClientContext(site_url).with_credentials(UserCredential(username,password))
request = RequestOptions("{0}/_api/web/".format(site_url))
response = ''
while response == '':
    try: 
        session = requests.Session()
        session.trust_env = False
        response = ctx.pending_request().execute_request_direct(request)
        break
    except:
        print("Connection refused by server")
        time.sleep(5)
        print("Trying again")
        continue
data = json.loads(response.content)
web_title = data['d']['Title']
print("Web title: {0}".format(web_title))
```

Comment: see if you can paste the code here and what error message you get.

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I am not able to understand the issue. I tried searching the issue on internet but was unable to find the solution. When I login to company's sharepoint website then my code runs successfully but if I don't login then it keeps on running in the loop printing "connection refused by server" "Trying again". It keeps on printing this. Why I put the loop is because many times code was unable to connect in one go so I put the loop with time.sleep(5) , so in 3-4 attempts it can connect with sharepoint.

Comment: do you have MFA enabled for the user account?

Comment: @GauravT no MFA is not enabled

Comment: @MEdwin - any suggestions, in the code